# App Script: how to return TotalRows of a BigQuery-Request in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have written an app script for Google Sheet which updates a table in BQ. The script should return among other information the total rows of the table. The script returns the job status and totalbytes but does not return the totalRows. I do not see a difference between the different values: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults

What do I have to change in order to get also TotalRows?

````
  // Need to provoke a drive dialog
  // DriveApp.getFiles()
  
  // Replace this value with your project ID and the name of the sheet to update.
  var projectId = 'my-project';
  var sheetName = 'my-sheet';

  // Use standard SQL to query BigQuery
  var request = {
    query: 'DROP TABLE `my-project.xyz.targetgroup_5_tbl`; CREATE TABLE `my-project.xyz.targetgroup_5_tbl` AS SELECT * FROM `waipu-app-prod.Access.targetgroup_5_std`;',
    useLegacySql: false
  };
  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
  var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;


  // Check on status of the Query Job.
  var sleepTimeMs = 500;
  while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    sleepTimeMs *= 2;
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
  }
  
  if (queryResults.jobComplete=true) {
    // Append the results.
    var status= queryResults.jobComplete;
    var dayc = new Date();
    var totalbytes = queryResults.totalBytesProcessed;
    var totalRows = queryResults.totalRows;

    var rows = [
                   ['target group',status,dayc,totalbytes,totalRows],      
               ]
    var status = queryResults.jobComplete; 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var currentSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    currentSheet.getRange(23,1, 1, 5).setValues(rows);
    
    console.info('%d rows inserted.', queryResults.totalRows);
  } else {
    console.info('No results found in BigQuery');
  }
}
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code just have a small error, in one of the comparisons, you used:

`if (queryResults.jobComplete=true) {`

Which always will evaluate to true because this is an assignation, not a comparison. To compare if jobComplete is true, you should use '==' instead, i.e.,

`if (queryResults.jobComplete==true) {`

Or even better, since jobComplete is already a boolean variable, you can simply do:

`if (queryResults.jobComplete) {`

Now, the reason why you're not getting `totalRows` is because you are executing a sql script, which doesn't return any rows. Even if you consider only the last part of the script, you are executing a `CREATE TABLE AS` statement, which doesn't return any rows.

I understand that you want to know how many rows were inserted on this table. There are many options to do so, which includes getting the table details, or execute a `SELECT COUNT` query; however, based on what you're doing in the sql script: deleting and re-creating a table I recommend you a different approach: Use the API method [Jobs.insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) to specify a destination table so you can execute your query as a `SELECT` statement. Finally, use the `writeDisposition:"WRITE_TRUNCATE"` to delete the previous data, as in your script.

Here's a code that you can use as a reference:

```js
var projectId = 'my-project';

// The request object changed to adapt to a Jobs.insert request
var request = {
  configuration: {
    query: {
      destinationTable: {
        projectId: projectId,
        datasetId: 'my-dataset',
        tableId: 'my-table'
      },
      query: 'SELECT * FROM ...', // Here goes the query used to create the table
      useLegacySql: false,
      writeDisposition: 'WRITE_TRUNCATE' // Truncate the data before writing it again
    }
  }
};

var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(request, projectId); // Use Jobs.insert instead of Jobs.query
var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;
```

Comment: Great! That did the trick :-) Thank you very much @Tlaquetzal!